# Peewee. How can I select all model items with joined foreignkey field with prefetched field?

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I have 3 models.

```py
from peewee import (
    PostgresqlDatabase,
    Model,
    CharField,
    ForeignKeyField,
    prefetch,
    JOIN_LEFT_OUTER
)

db = PostgresqlDatabase("***", user='***', password='***')


class Model1(Model):
    name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db


class Model2(Model):
    name = CharField()
    model1 = ForeignKeyField(Model1)

    class Meta:
        database = db


class Model3(Model):
    name = CharField()
    model1 = ForeignKeyField(Model1)

    class Meta:
        database = db


def main():
    model1_prefetched = prefetch(Model1.select(Model1), Model3.select(Model3)).select()
    query = Model2.select(Model2.name, model1_prefetched.c.model1, model1_prefetched.c.model3).join(model1_prefetched, join_type=JOIN_LEFT_OUTER, on=(Model2.model1_id==model1_prefetched.c.id))
    model2_objects = list(query.execute())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to select all data from **Model2** joined with **Model1** and prefetch all **Model3-objects** to every **Model1-object**.
I don't understand how I can do it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
query = Model2.select()
prefetch(query, Model1, Model3)
model3_list = list(query.execute())
```